# Log Exception Error on Network

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, global-asax

I want to log Exception in case of error on network. I have made changes in global.asax file and generated log file in it. The code works fine on localhost but when I upload the dll of global.asax file on another server and change the web config according to network credentials similar to the localhost. In case of error the method doesnot seem to work nor the file is created to write the exception. Please help

```
 void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
            try
            {
                DffUtility.AddCookie("verystart", "Very start of error");
                Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

                Uri refurl = Request.UrlReferrer;
                DffUtility.AddCookie("star655", "getting exception start");
                string networkLogFolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Logpath"] + "\\" + DffUtility.WebSiteInfo.Folder + "\\" + DffUtility.WebSiteInfo.ThemeName + "\\";
                DffUtility.AddCookie("path", networkLogFolderPath.ToString());
                Network.connectToRemote(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Logpath"],
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["networkusername"],
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pass"]);
                string LogFolderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ExceptionLogFiles/");
                string filePath = networkLogFolderPath;


                string stacktracemessage, stacktrace, Errormsg, extype, exurl;
                stacktracemessage = (exc.InnerException).Message;

                stacktrace = exc.ToString();

                Errormsg = exc.GetType().Name.ToString();
                extype = exc.GetType().ToString();
                exurl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();

                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)))
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
                if (DffUtility.Country > 0)
                {
                    if (DffUtility.RegionArea > 0)
                    {
                        if (DffUtility.RegionCity > 0)
                        {
                            if (DffUtility.ProdID > 0)
                            {
                                filePath = (filePath + "Product_" + DffUtility.ProdID + "_" + DffUtility.RegionCity + "_" + DffUtility.RegionArea + "_" + DffUtility.Country + ".txt");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                filePath = (filePath + "City_" + DffUtility.RegionCity + "_" + DffUtility.RegionArea + "_" + DffUtility.Country + ".txt");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            filePath = (filePath + "Area_" + DffUtility.RegionArea + "_" + DffUtility.Country + ".txt");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filePath = (filePath + "Country_" + DffUtility.Country + ".txt");

                        DffUtility.AddCookie("start8", "After generating product file");
                    }
                }
                System.IO.File.Create(filePath).Dispose();

                using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(filePath))
                {
                    string logFormat = Environment.NewLine + " " + Environment.NewLine;

                    DffUtility.AddCookie("start6", "in");
                    string error = "Error Message:" + " " + Errormsg + logFormat + "Exception Type:" + " " + extype + logFormat + " Error Page Url:" + " " + exurl + logFormat + " StackTraceMessage:" + " " + stacktracemessage + logFormat + " StackTrace:" + " " + stacktrace + logFormat + " " + refurl + logFormat;
                    sw.WriteLine("-----------Exception Details on " + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "-----------------");
                    sw.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

                    sw.WriteLine(error);

                    sw.WriteLine(logFormat);
                    sw.Flush();
                    sw.Close();
                    DffUtility.AddCookie("start4", " after getting generated log");
                }
```

Comment: May be its permission issue, do iis application pool user have rights to write on the path you specified ?
try giving write access to everyone on the folder,

Comment: Please check that you have permission of read, write to that server... It may be issue with permission only.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your application runs under NETWORK SERVICE account (by default) and don't have permissions to write in **ExceptionLogFiles** folder. Add user **Everyone** in folder properties and grant him that permission

Comment: I did that I tested manually the file is created and has all permissions. Is the global.asax.dll the only dll generated in case of error?

Comment: But you said that log file isn't creating. So what is actually goes wrong?

Comment: have you tried by restarting your application pool. and if file is creating then what's wrong? Please elaborate your actual query.

Comment: basically the log file is created on network on localhost while testing locally. But does not seem to work on cross domain with the same code and log file also not generated in case of error page on domain the exception shows no result.

Comment: Than it may be something wrong with your web.config file, leading to situation when Application_Error is not working as expected